# Android Studio - change jython interpeter, working with monkeyrunner

Tags: android, android-studio, monkeyrunner, jython-2.7

I'm using Android Studio, and in the SDK that's installed, there is the
`monkeyrunner, Jython` , in tools, from what I can tell `monkeyrunner` uses 'jython'.

However the jython used is an old version 2.5(I have installed the newest SDK for `Android Studio`)

How can i change the interpreter for jython to use the more updated version, 2.7.0, that exists in the official jython site?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get a chance to change the jython version to latest? I want to do the same. Please share me.

Comment: plz see my question ... that very helpful for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103540/why-android-studio-cannot-run-the-project-with-python

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile `monkeyrunner.jar` to change jython version and you may have to fix lot of issues.

Alternatively, you can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) that uses python and works perfectly with [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/specials/pycharm/pycharm.html).